# New norms on $L^2$

Tags: integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Consider the space $X = L^2(\mathbb{R})$. For $f \in X$ and $\theta > 0$ define:

$$
\| f \|_\theta := \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-2 \theta |x|}| \hat f(x) |^2 \, dx,
$$

and

$$
\| f \|_{X_\theta} := \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)}\|_\theta .
$$

**Question:** Take $\alpha > 0$. Then, for $\theta > \alpha$, clearly:

$$
\| f \|_{X_\theta} \leq \| f \|_{X_\alpha}.
$$

But is it true that

$$
 \limsup_{\theta \rightarrow \alpha+} \|f\|_{X_\theta} =  \|f\|_{X_\alpha}?
$$

Comment: Sure, use dominated convergence.

Comment: Alright, so if I pick an arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{R}$, I take it that dominated convergence gives me: 

$$ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow \alpha+} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)}\|_\theta = \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)}\|_\alpha.$$

And 

$$ \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \lim_{\theta \rightarrow \alpha+} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)}\|_\theta =  \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)}\|_\alpha.$$


But can I (swap $\sup$ with $\lim$ and) infer that:

$$\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \alpha+}  \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}}  \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)}\|_\theta =  \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)}\|_\alpha?$$

Comment: I suppose that, for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$
\sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)} \|_\theta \leq \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \lim_{\theta \rightarrow \alpha+} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)} \|_\theta,$$

so

$$ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow \alpha+} \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)} \|_\theta \leq \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \lim_{\theta \rightarrow \alpha+} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)} \|_\theta,$$

Comment: The RHS of the last inequality is then is bdd by $\sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \|f \chi_{(-\infty, a)} \|_\alpha$, since for any $a$,

$$
\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \alpha+} \| f \chi_{(-\infty, a)} \|_\theta \leq \| f \chi_{(-\infty, a)} \|_\alpha.
$$

Sure hope I'm getting this right...